# Esper Compare With Previous event

Tags: esper

I am new with Esper so i am unable to solve a simple problem. All i have to do is to get the difference of current close of bar with the previous close of bar. Whats the smartest way to approach this problem in esper?

Result= CurrentBar.Close - PreviousBar.Close.

**EDIT**:

I am using following piece of code will this work?

```
select
prev(0,close) - prev(1,close) as return,
security
from
Bar.win:length(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "prev()" special function.